# Error : Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, caldroid

I pass the image from drawable reference like follows

> Bitmap bitmap = mImageGenerator.generateDateImage(calendar,
>   R.drawable.data);

it throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas
>   constructor

I use same exact statement in other activity and it works fine.

Problem :

> mImageGenerator.generateDateImage is locked class from caldroid
>   (https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

so cant change anything in it.

**I just noticed that this occurs on NOUGAT**
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is to add

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inMutable = true;<<<<<<
```

in custom created class ownImageGenerator